# Can I or SHOULD I find an object by the object_id attribute in ruby?

Tags: ruby, search, indexing, find

When I make a new object, let's say

```
o = Object.new
```

This object has an id,

```
o.object_id 
#=> ########
```

I also make several other objects, using the Object class. What would be the best way to have ruby find the object 'o' by using the object_id attribute? I am thinking in terms of something like

```
search_id = o.object_id
search_result = Object.find(search_id)
```

Where 'search_results' would be the object corresponding to 'search_id'. Also, I would definitely appreciate an altogether different approach to indexing objects and retrieving them by a guid or something. Thanks so much!

Hah, well I guess I really just need to think about this in the context of a database and just use MySQL queries or those of whatever DB I choose to find the object. The more I think about it, the only possible things that would be accessible through this imaginary 'find()' method would be things that are newly created or 'active'? Sorry for making this a crappy question.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
irb(main):002:0> s1 = "foo"
#=> "foo"
irb(main):003:0> s2 = ObjectSpace._id2ref(s1.object_id)
#=> "foo"
irb(main):004:0> s2.object_id == s1.object_id
#=> true
irb(main):005:0> s2[0] = "z"
#=> "z"
irb(main):006:0> s1
#=> "zoo"
```

Should you do this? I'll leave that up to you. There are less geeky ways to store an object with a serializable `id` (e.g. in an Array and returning the index). One problem you may run into is that if the only 'reference' you keep to an object is the `object_id`, the object can be collected by GC when you're not looking.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back here. This definitely answered my basic question. I kinda wrapped some confusing secondary stuff in there, but I'll deal with that on my own or in another question at some point.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: if he would keep all instances created by his Class in a class-variable, he could prevent them from being garbage collected, and he could use the object_id to reference them