# Something like reference to the variable

Tags: c++, ruby

How can I do this in Ruby?
For example, in Ruby:

```
a = [1,2,3]
h= {vara: a} 
p h[:vara] # [1,2,3]

a = [42,43,44]
p h[:vara] # [1,2,3] - still the same
```

Hash shows the same results (array `[1,2,3]`) although I have changed `a`.
As for this example, I want hash shows different results when `a` changes:

```
a = [1,2,3]
h= {vara: a} 
p h[:vara] # [1,2,3]

a = [42,43,44]
p h[:vara] # [42,43,44] - changed!
```

How to do it in general case - variable nor container (hash in above example) isn't specified?

For example, in the C++ you can use *reference*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib>
int main(void)
{
   int a = 10;
   int &var = a;
   std::cout<< "\na = "<< a <<"\n";
   a = 42;
   std::cout<< "\nnew var = " << var << "\n"; //
   std::cout<< "\nnew a = " << a << "\n";

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

will produce:

```
a = 10

new var = 42

new a = 42
```

Is there something like this in the Ruby?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345755/object-assignment-in-ruby

Comment: @steenslag how this relate/help in my problem?

Answer (score 4):

You simply replace the containment of the instance of the `Array` with the `#replace` method, because the `=` assignment operator just assing to a variable name *an other instance*:

```
a = [1,2,3]
h = {vara: a} 
h[:vara]
# => [1,2,3]

a.replace [42,43,44]
h[:vara]
# => [42, 43, 44]
```

Comment: Ah, damn it, I was about to post my copy of this. :)

Comment: It's `Array#replace`, not `Hash#replace`, by the way.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev jey =)

Comment: Let me copy comment for above answer => The problem with replace is that it is not in every class. As I have checked only String, Array, Hash contain this method. +1 because it works for some part of ruby classes.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby has references, but they're more like C++ pointers (with transparent dereferencing).

There's no equivalent of C/C++ references. You can always write a C extension, though.

Instead of completely replacing "a" **reference itself**, you can replace the content of what **it points to**.

```
a = [1,2,3]
h= {vara: a} 
p h[:vara] 

a.replace([40, 41, 42]) # <== note here
p h[:vara] 
# >> [1, 2, 3]
# >> [40, 41, 42]
```

In this case, both `h[:para]` and `a` are still pointing to the same array. But when you assign to `a`, the link breaks.

Comment: The problem with `replace` is that it is not in every class. As I have checked only `String`, `Array`, `Hash` contain this method. +1 because it works for some part of ruby classes. ps. SO says that you were faster (few minutes).

Comment: I was the first, yes. But @Малъ posted code with replace a few seconds before I updated my answer. :)

Comment: @DarekNędza: anyway, apart from getting to low-level (C ext), I don't know what can be done here.